# How do I uninstall icons installed with ocs-url?

Tags: uninstall

I installed some icons using ocs-url.
https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1136805/

icon i am referring to: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1209330

However when I go to the /usr/shared/icons or /usr/share/pixmaps location.
I can't find the folder containing the icons.
however, the icons are still usable in my gnome tweaks. How do I uninstall icons installed with ocs-url?

Thank you!

Comment: you forgot to check /home/$USER/.local/ for the fonts. Fonts are either system wide or single user.

Comment: awesome! thank you so much! now I know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall the icon you downloaded from OSC URL application, you can simply go to `~/.local/share/icons` and here you can find all the icon packs installed on your system. And you can easily remove them from here. But be careful if you remove the current icon pack (means the one your PC is using), you may run into trouble.